# Entity Framework - Index Where Not NULL

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq, indexing

I have a table that contains 3 columns and 6 foreign keys.
Code,TypeCode,Ref1,Ref2,Ref3,Ref4,Ref5,Ref6,SomeColumnOutOfIndex.  I made an unique index constraint on all fields (combination). Now when I query I know that for example all foreign keys are null except for one. When I filter:
`Where(x=> x.Code == "something" && TypeCode == 'somethingtype' && Ref1 == null && Ref2 == null && Ref3 == null && Ref4 != null && Ref5 == null && Ref6 == null && SomeColumnOutOfIndex == "X")`
Entity Framework reorganizes it and puts the order: Code,SomeColumnOutOfIndex,TypeCode,Ref4,Ref1,Ref2,Ref3,Ref5,Ref6. Which means it does not hit the index!

What would be a good approach? Saying that all ForeignKeys are not equal to for example '0' hits the index but that doesn't filter at all. I know that one of the columns is not null and the others must be.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Can you provide [mcve].

Comment: Hi, just created a test app to simulate and I'm also not able to reproduce this. Difference is automapper - next step is adding this to my test setup. Will get back to you.

Comment: Shouldn't SQL figure out the index applicability regardless of order? What SQL are you using?

Comment: Azure SQL  (test project as Ivan Stoev suggested was against a localdb)

Comment: Tried with AutoMapper, same version as on my other solution. Not able to reproduce the issue. I'm not sure what else it could be. It's literally the same.

Comment: Reproduced it:  I miss that at the end I have another PropertyOutsideOfIndex=="X" and this is causing it. My test project.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ao1bVTxfyzh-d21Nok8R9BxAyoE